# finding specific service that is making IMDSv1 calls on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

1 - can we find a specific service that is making IMDSv1 calls from ec2 instance using command line interface?

2 - Which ec2 metadata category content the list of services the instance is listening to?

I would like to have an appropriate approach to overcome this concern

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the list of services the instance is listening to". On the IMDSv1 requests, you might need to capture local network traffic (e.g. using tcpdump) to determine which process is making those requests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.